# ¿Como tomar un resultado, buscar alguna de las palabras inconvenientes de un array y cambiarla por otra palabra de otro array segun el orden?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este input :

```html
<form action="">
            Primer Apellido <br>
            <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="paterno" /     onkeyup="mayus(this);" onkeypress="Genera()">
            <br>
        </form>
```

Quiero que cuando escriba por ejemplo "COLA" la cambie por "COLX" y que esto pase con todas las demas palabras que estan en este array :

```
var inconvenientes2 = [ 'BACA', 'LOCA', 'BUEY', 'COLA' ];
```

Y deben cambiarse por las palabras de este array segun el orden :

```
var inconvenientes2 = [ 'BACX', 'LOCX', 'BUEX', 'COLX' ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, podrías usar la función indexOf la cual te devuelve el indice si lo encuentra y -1 sino, una vez encontrada la palabra lo que haces es cambiar el valor del input con el segundo array a través del indice.

```js
var inconvenientes1 = [ 'BACA', 'LOCA', 'BUEY', 'COLA' ];
var inconvenientes2 = [ 'BACX', 'LOCX', 'BUEX', 'COLX' ];

function genera(self){
  const index = inconvenientes1.indexOf(self.value);
  if(index !== -1){
     self.value = inconvenientes2[index];
  }
}

function mayus(self){
  self.value = self.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="apellidos" id="paterno" oninput="mayus(this)" onkeyup="genera(this)">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, pero que pasa si quiero buscar la palabra desde un "div" donde se esta mostrando la palabra.. como lo hago?.. Intento adaptarlo a esto que tengo :  var result = document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = custom;
    
    
    const index = inconvenientes1.indexOf(result);
    if(index !== -1){
        result = inconvenientes2[index];
    }

Comment: de nada, no sé si te he entendido pero supongo que quieres decir que las palabras se encuentren en un div y quieras sustituir esas palabras, para ello tienes que hacer < var texto = document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML; >           
y ahora hacer un replace por cada palabra por ejemplo en tu caso           < texto.replace(inconveniente1[0],inconveniente2[0] ); >                       esto iría en un for sustituyendo el 0 por el indice y una vez terminado  lo muestras de nuevo <document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = texto>, otra opción seria usar expresiones regulares.

Comment: Ya lo hice, pero algo pasa con el "for" que no me da bien el recorrido:  for(var i = 0; i<inconvenientes1.length;i++){
    var result = document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = custom;
    var res = result.replace(inconvenientes1[i],inconvenientes2[i]);
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = res;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Buenas amigo tienes que obtener el valor del `input` despues hacer un `forEach` para iterar el array `inconvenientes1` y comparar si lo que el usuario escribe coincide con algun valor en el array, si coincide obtenemos el index y asignamos un nuevo valor al input con el `inconvenientes2[index]`

Espero te ayude.

**Ejemplo funcional**

> **Nota**: para el ejemplo se usa la libreria de javascript **jquery** se puede hacer sin problema también con javascript vanilla pero por rapidez use jquery.

```js
var inconvenientes1 = [ 'BACA', 'LOCA', 'BUEY', 'COLA' ];
var inconvenientes2 = [ 'BACX', 'LOCX', 'BUEX', 'COLX' ];
$("#paterno").keyup(function(){
   var valor = $(this).val()
  inconvenientes1.forEach(function(item,index){
    if(item == valor.toUpperCase()){
    $("#paterno").val(inconvenientes2[index])
      console.log(inconvenientes2[index])
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="">Primer apellido</label>
  <input id="paterno" type="text" name="" value="">
```